# searching the string with the time in log file using shell script by passing variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, grep

I want to search a string and subtract the time that is found from the current time. When used, the script should show the lines from that time or from the very next log time frame.

I'm able to search the string and subtract the time from the current time, but it is searching the exact time and giving a result.

I want the script to look for the exact time. If the exact time is not found, it should show the result from whatever the nearest logged time to current time and it should show the log lines.

Expected Output:

If the both string and time not finding in log file, script should be intelligent to pick from the nearest log time and show result from that time to current time how many logs are there with that string.

Comment: I have cleaned up your post, but the grammar needs to be cleaned up to better relay your question's intentions.

Comment: Really  thanks 'root',  and up to know i didnt get any answers.
Generally how many days of time it will take to answer my question.

Comment: Could you include the expected output when running your script (with those parameters) for that log file? Your explanation of what you want is not very clear. Also, what is the second parameter for? ("Script start at")

Comment: @Ziggy Crueltyfree Zeitgeiste I have edited the question and added expected out put.

Comment: @root as I'm new to this site, kindly help on this, I just edited my question, again this question looks uneven and very clumsy., how can I edit that with correctly

Comment: @user267747 See [editing-help](http://superuser.com/editing-help). Clear questions that indicate the steps you have already taken to resolve your problem will attract attention. Also see [no one answers](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers).

Comment: @user267747 thanks for clarifying, but it is still difficult to grasp what you need. You've written the contents of the log file again (there was certainly no need for that!), instead of writing what the *expected output* from the program should look like. Also, about the second parameter: would the log file have lines *other* than "Script start at"? Finally, the date and time formatting in the log (the one on the right) has an odd formatting (dash between day and hour, and a single digit for seconds): is this intentional or it was a typo/copy-paste error?

Comment: @Ziggy Crueltyfree Zeitgeister for suppose I'm searching like this:
./combination.sh /home/logs/test.log "start" "-20 min"

Comment: @Ziggy Crueltyfree Zeitgeister that right side date was typo error.

For suppose I'm searching like this:
>> ./combination.sh /home/user/logs/script.log "start" "-20 min" <<

For the above script I will get the result as shown in below:
>> OK: start 16/03/25 12:46 found on /home/user/logs/script.log <<

But if the search time not there in log file it will give the result as shown below:
>> CRITICAL - start 16/03/25 12:46 not found on /home/user/logs/script.log <<

Comment: My expectation is, script should find and show the log from before minute or hours of search time to next minute or hour of search time or hours if the search time not there in log file. 
Eg: if i search "start"  "-21 min" my search string and time("start" 12:45) not found in log, then it should give result something like this
>> CRITICAL - start 16/03/25 12:45 not found on /home/user/logs/script.log <<

The next minute log found:
>> OK: start 16/03/25 12:46 found on /home/user/logs/script.log <<

Comment: Script should find and show the log from before minute or hours of search time to next minute or hour of search time if the search time not found.
Eg: if i search "start"  "-21 min" my search string and time("start" 12:45) not found in log, then

>> CRITICAL - start 16/03/25 12:45 not found on /home/user/logs/script.log <<

The next minute log found:
>> OK: start 16/03/25 12:46 found on /home/user/logs/script.log <<
>> OK: start 16/03/25 12:47 found on /home/user/logs/script.log <<
... so on up to current time

means the cron or script not ran and not filed the log at 12:45

Answer (score 0):

The following script assumes you want to find the text in parameter 2, followed by `:`, followed by the date in parameter 3 formatted as `YYYY-M-D-h:m:s`, i.e. without leading zeroes, as per the snippet in your question.

```
#!/bin/bash

logfile="$1"
message="$2"
timestamp=$(printf '%d-%d-%d-%d:%d:%d' `date -d "$3" +"%Y %m %d %H %M %S"`)

if grep -q "^../../.. ..:..:.. $message : $timestamp\$" "$logfile"; then
  echo "OK: $message $timestamp found on $logfile"
else
  echo "CRITICAL - $message $timestamp not found on $logfile"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! but my bad, this not met my requirement.

Comment: I didn't implement this "_If the both string and time not finding in log file, script should be intelligent to pick from the nearest log time and show result from that time to current time how many logs are there with that string_" because is too confusing. "Nearest": backwards or forwards? Show what result? How many logs are there with that string? What? This is why I requested you (a number of times) to include the expected output, as an execution mock: include command run, and following what is the expected output, and perhaps include two or three of these with different outcomes.